# Title case capitalising letter after ‘

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

Is there a .net **bug** causing the following code to *capitalise* the `S`, giving `"Ben’S Pies"`?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string value = "ben’s pies";
        string titleCase = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value);
        Console.WriteLine(titleCase);    
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the output at: https://rextester.com/ (where I tried it).

Comment: `"ben's pies"` - *apostroph* instead of *RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you print a dump of the `value`:

```
  string value = "ben’s pies";

  Console.Write(string.Join(" ", value.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x4"))));
```

You'll get

> 0062 0065 006e **2019** 0073 0020 0070 0069 0065 0073

Now, let's have a look for *Unicode U+2019*

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm

And we see that `’` is not an *apostroph*, but "RIGHT SINGLE **QUOTATION MARK** (U+2019)." That's why `ToTitleCase` does work right (it capitalizes the word after a *punctuation* - a quotation mark). To amend your example put apostroph instead of quotation:

```
 string value = "ben's pies";

 // Ben's Pies
 string titleCase = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value);
```

Comment: Aha. It seems I’ve always mistakenly thought the apostrophe on the iPad keyboard was on the K letter. Now looking at it I need to hold down the K key and select the third pop up. I’m guessing most people make that mistake so I may need to replace it programmatically first since it is meant to come from a webpage text box that a user enters their company name into.

Comment: @user1946932: Alas, quotations, apostrophes and strokes are easy to mix.

Comment: Update: After reading around the internet I found that iOS11+ has Settings>Keyboard>Smart Punctuation>On which immediately converts normal apostrophes (0x27) entered via the K key into "prettier" (0x2019) RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK.

Comment: @user1946932: I see; a lot of users are accustomed to put *apostrophes* as a *single quotations* (*minus* instead of *dashes* and *hyphens* etc.): I would say, 'what a bad practice!'. Apple tried to solve the issue, but it seems it actaully brought more problems.

Comment: Actually U+2019 doubles as (curly) apostrophe. You wouldn't use the straight apostrophe (U+0027) in professional typography. See http://smartquotesforsmartpeople.com/. So I consider this behavior of ToTitleCase to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

`ToTitleCase` does indeed seem to treat the right single quotation mark as a separator between the words it converts to title case. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) says:

> the ToTitleCase method provides an arbitrary casing behavior which is not necessarily linguistically correct. A linguistically correct solution would require additional rules, and the current algorithm is somewhat simpler and faster. We reserve the right to make this API slower in the future.

Comment: Sorry, but `’` in the example is **not** an apostroph, but a "RIGHT SINGLE *QUOTATION MARK* (U+2019)". Please, put `"ben's pies"` with apostroph and see that `s` is *not capitalized* in this case

Comment: Thanks. You were right. iPad keyboard as described above.